# How To Display Text in Bokeh While Preserving Line Gaps

Tags: html, python-3.x, text, bokeh

I am trying to generate a report consisting of plots and some text using Bokeh 2.0.1, and I am trying to preserve the original line gaps in the text that I feed into `bokeh.layouts.gridplot`.

However, I see that all the line gaps get removed after the HTML file is generated, and essentially, all paragraphs get merged into one continuous sentence. I am not sure why that is happening. I didn't find much help in the Bokeh documentation regarding this issue.

Here's a minimal example of the section of the code I am trying to get to work.

```
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import Paragraph
from bokeh.plotting import output_file, save

sampText = "PARAGRAPH 1: This is a minimal example of a text. This is a minimal example of a text. This is a minimal example of a text. This is a minimal example of a text. This is a minimal example of a text. This is a minimal example of a text.\n

PARAGRAPH 2: This is a minimal example of a text. This is a minimal example of a text. This is a minimal example of a text. This is a minimal example of a text. This is a minimal example of a text."

fig1 = ...

fig2 = ...

text = Paragraph(text = sampText, width = 1500, height_policy = "auto", style = {'fontsize': '10pt', 'color': 'black', 'font-family': 'arial'})

output_file(filename = "myMinimalExampleOutput" + ".html")
output = gridplot([fig1, fig2, text], ncols = 1, plot_width = 1500, sizing_mode = 'scale_width')
save(output)
```

Could someone please point out why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how HTML works - it removes all "unnecessary" whitespace from the text.

For your two paragraphs to work, you have to wrap each of them in `<p></p>`. But since `Paragraph` generates the same tag, you can't use that class. Use the regular `Div` and set its `text` input parameter to the HTML that you want to be rendered.

```py
Div(text='<p>paragraph 1</p><p>paragraph 2</p>')
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem. I wasn't aware of the Div class in Bokeh.